# TeX Live not compiling from TeXnicCenter

Tags: errors, texlive, compiling, windows, texniccenter

Due to problems with `psfragfig` and MiKTeX I wanted to switch to TeX Live and TeXnicCenter instead (on Windows 8).

However it does not compile even the smallest MWE in TeXnicCenter. I always get the error message that the file I want to compile is not found.

From the command line I have no problems.

Do you know what is causing this error?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do you have TeX Live now fully installed instead of MiKTeX or as portable version? Did you change the output profile entries in TeXnicCenter?

Comment: Why don't you try with some other editors, like TeXStudio or Texmaker? If it works there, then maybe there is a problem with TeXnicCenter.

Comment: Sorry for not answering so long. I was out cold with a fever for a week.
TeX Live is fully installed instead of MiKTeX. I changed the output profiles correctly. LaTeX is starting it is just not finding the file.
I wanted to use the comfortable error jumping in TeXnicCenter, that´s why I use it.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice to install TeXnicCenter is:

1. If you have installed an TeX distribution and TeXnicCenter **deinstall** both!
2. **Reboot** the computer!
3. **Install** and **upate** the TeX distribution, you want to use.
4. When the installation of the TeX distribution is finished (important!), please **reboot**!
5. Download the current TeXnicCenter installer program and **install** it.  **The advantage** of this is that TeXnicCenter installer is able to recognize the installed TeX distribution and uses then the related configuration for TeXnicCenter.